# Decoding by libjpeg -> Encoding by x264, strange artefacts on frames

Tags: c++, qt, libjpeg, libx264

I have a collection of jpeg, which must be decoded by lib jpeg, and after it, encoded by x264 (after it encoded packets are streamed via rtmp).
Code I used for decoding:

```
struct my_error_mgr 
{   
    struct jpeg_error_mgr pub;
    jmp_buf setjmp_buffer;
};
typedef my_error_mgr *my_error_ptr;

METHODDEF(void) my_error_exit (j_common_ptr cinfo)
{
    my_error_ptr myerr = (my_error_ptr) cinfo->err;
    (*cinfo->err->output_message) (cinfo);
    longjmp(myerr->setjmp_buffer, 1);   
}

void init_source(j_decompress_ptr ptr)
{
    Q_UNUSED(ptr)
}

boolean fill_input_buffer(j_decompress_ptr ptr) 
{
     Q_UNUSED(ptr)
    return TRUE;
}

void term_source(j_decompress_ptr ptr)
{
    Q_UNUSED(ptr)
}

void skip_input_data(j_decompress_ptr ptr, long num_bytes)
{
    if(num_bytes>0) 
    {
        ptr->src->next_input_byte+=(size_t)num_bytes;
        ptr->src->bytes_in_buffer-=(size_t)num_bytes;   
    }
}

EtherDecoder::EtherDecoder(QObject *parent):
QObject(parent)
{
}

void EtherDecoder::dataBlockReady(QByteArray data)
{
    jpeg_decompress_struct decompressInfo;
    jpeg_create_decompress(&decompressInfo);
    my_error_mgr err;
    decompressInfo.do_fancy_upsampling = FALSE;
    decompressInfo.src = (jpeg_source_mgr *) (*decompressInfo.mem->alloc_small)       ((j_common_ptr) &decompressInfo, JPOOL_PERMANENT, sizeof(jpeg_source_mgr));
    decompressInfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&err.pub);
    err.pub.error_exit = my_error_exit;
    if (setjmp(err.setjmp_buffer))  
    {
        jpeg_destroy_decompress(&decompressInfo);
        return; 
    }
    decompressInfo.src->init_source = init_source;
    decompressInfo.src->resync_to_restart = jpeg_resync_to_restart;
    decompressInfo.src->fill_input_buffer = fill_input_buffer;
    decompressInfo.src->skip_input_data = skip_input_data;
    decompressInfo.src->term_source = term_source;
    decompressInfo.src->next_input_byte = reinterpret_cast<const JOCTET*>(data.data());
    decompressInfo.src->bytes_in_buffer = data.size();
    jpeg_read_header(&decompressInfo, TRUE);
    jpeg_start_decompress(&decompressInfo);
    int size = 0;
    int n_samples = 0;
    char *samples = new char[5242880];
    char *reserv = samples;
    while (decompressInfo.output_scanline < decompressInfo.output_height)   
    {
        n_samples = jpeg_read_scanlines(&decompressInfo, (JSAMPARRAY) &samples, 1);
        samples += n_samples * decompressInfo.image_width * decompressInfo.num_components;
        size += n_samples * decompressInfo.image_width * decompressInfo.num_components; 
    }
    jpeg_finish_decompress(&decompressInfo);
    QByteArray output(reserv, size);
    emit frameReady(output, decompressInfo.output_width, decompressInfo.output_height);
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&decompressInfo);
    delete[] reserv;
}
```

When I emit frameReady signal, I send data to Encoder, method, where I init Encedor looks like:

```
bool EtherEncoder::initEncoder(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    x264_param_t param;
    x264_param_default_preset(&param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
    param.i_width=width;
    param.i_height=height;
    param.i_frame_total=0;
    param.i_csp=X264_CSP_I420;
    param.i_timebase_num=1;
    param.i_timebase_den=96000;
    param.b_annexb=true;
    param.b_repeat_headers=false;
    x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass(&param);
    x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "baseline");
    _context=x264_encoder_open(&param);
    if(!_context)
        return false;
    int nal_count;
    x264_nal_t *nals;
    if(x264_encoder_headers(_context, &nals, &nal_count)<0) 
    {
        x264_encoder_close(_context);
        _context=0;
        return false;   
    }
    _extradata=QByteArray();
    _width=width;
    _height=height;
    if(nal_count>0) 
    {
        _extradata=QByteArray(
            (const char *)nals[0].p_payload,
            nals[nal_count-1].p_payload+nals[nal_count-1].i_payload-nals[0].p_payload); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

And encoding method:

```
void EtherEncoder::onFrameReady(QByteArray data, int width, int height)
{
    while(data.size()>0)    
    {
        if(!_context && initEncoder(width, height))
        {
            _timestampDelta=realTimestamp();
        }
        if(_context)
        {
            x264_picture_t pic;
            x264_picture_init(&pic);
            pic.i_type=X264_TYPE_AUTO;
            pic.i_pts=_timestampDelta*96000;
            pic.img.i_csp=X264_CSP_I420;
            pic.img.i_plane=3;
            int planeSize = width*height;
            uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)data.data();
            pic.img.plane[0]=p;
            p+=planeSize;
            pic.img.plane[1]=p;
            p+=planeSize/4;
            pic.img.plane[2]=p;
            pic.img.i_stride[0]=width;
            pic.img.i_stride[1]=width/2;
            pic.img.i_stride[2]=width/2;
            if(_forceKeyFrame)
            {
                pic.i_type=X264_TYPE_I;
                _forceKeyFrame=false;
            }
            int nal_count;
            x264_nal_t *nals;
            int rc=x264_encoder_encode(_context, &nals, &nal_count, &pic, &pic);
            if(rc>0)
            {
                _mutex.lock();
                _packets.push_back(
                    Packet(
                        QByteArray(
                            (const char *)nals[0].p_payload,         nals[nal_count-    1].p_payload+nals[nal_count-1].i_payload-nals[0].p_payload),
                        _timestampDelta/96.0,
                        _timestampDelta/96.0,
                        pic.b_keyframe));
                _timestampDelta+=40;
                data.clear();
                _mutex.unlock();
                emit onPacketReady();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Decoding and encoding proceeds without errors, at the end I get valid video stream, but, it seems that in one of this steps I set Invalid data for decoder/encoder. I get only 1/4 part of image (top-left, as I understood) and it has invalid color and come color stripes. Maybe I set invalid strides and planes when encode  frame, or maybe my setting data for libjpeg decoder is incorrect.. Please ask questions about my code, I'll try to make some explanations for you. I explodes my brain.. Thank you.